# Problems with _netrc, still getting clone failed

Tags: git-gui

I've followed this [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/ardupilot-mega/wiki/Git) on setting up git-gui so I can get access to google code git repositories but I am still getting clone failed. I really don't understand the problem. I have made a _netrc file and I have created a HOME environmental variable yet the problem is still there.

Is there anyone out there who could shed some light on this situation? It would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug the process with a:

```
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
git clone https://code.google.com/p/yourProject
```

Your environment variable `%HOME%` should reference an existing directory (not necessarily `C:\HOME` as in the tutorial, but any path you want), where `_netrc` has been created.

Then, make sure your `%HOME%\_netrc` file does contain:

```
machine code.google.com
login (your Gmail login, which is usually your email address)
password (your Gmail password)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I've debugged the process and I've tried cloning the google code git repository through gui bash and I get an error saying that the progam can't start because libidn-11.dll is missing?

Comment: @MDavies Then check your PATH: msysgit should be first. libidn-11.dll is only used by GoW (Gnu On Windows https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki)

Comment: msysgit isn't in my path. It seems I have no msysgit directory on my computer. All I have is "C:\Program Files(x86)\bin" in my PATH.

Comment: @MDavies then go to the folder where you installed your msysgit program (It doesn't have to be called msysgit), and launch `git-cmd.bat`. Run in it `git-gui`.

Comment: I assume this is the gitk.cmd file in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd" directory? Because I don't have a git-cmd.bat file where (I'm assuming) msysgit is installed. When I run it I get a popup telling me "Cannot find a git repository here."

Comment: @MDavies then don't rely on the broken install: download the 7z archive (https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=7z&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount), unzip it anywhere, and launch the `git-cmd.bat`.

Comment: Done that and I'm still receiving that libidn-11.dll missing problem when I try cloning an existing repository. Sorry about this.

Comment: @MDavies that is a path issue, then: check `%PATH%` in your `git-cmd.bat` session, and try to keep it minimal.

Comment: I've changed the `%PATH%` to be that of the bin for the unzipped 7z archive. So: `C:\Users\xxx\msysgit\bin` still having that dll problem. I checked the `%PATH%` in the `git-cmd.bat` and it comes out as `C:\Users\xxx\msysgit\\bin`

Comment: @MDavies Did you simplify (just in a DOS session) your PATH? As in `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-1.8.4-preview20130916\bin`

Comment: Well, my path in the DOS session isn't like that, it is as I said; just `C:\Users\xxx\msysgit\\bin`

Comment: @MDavies I understand your git path differs, but my point was to simplify your %PATH% until it remains only the bare minimum for windows, plus the path to your msysgit. And see if the error persists then.

Comment: I see. I'll look into it. Thanks for your help. I'll try it and I'll probably put it to one side for a while as I have other things I need to look at. And if all else fails I can just use Tortoise SVN.